# How to actually boot Ubuntu once installed?

Tags: usb, windows

I've successfully installed onto a USB drive, I've booted from the USB drive and got a menu with 4 options;

- Try Ubuntu without installing.
- Install Ubuntu.
- OEM Install (For manufacturers).
- Can't remember the 4th.

I selected the second - Install Ubuntu. Once I'd finished the installation it told me I needed to reboot in order to complete the installation. When I'd rebooted with the USB still in, it brings me back to the same menu with the 4 options. When I've rebooted without the USB, it boots Windows. Have I done something wrong?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I install Ubuntu?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/6328/how-do-i-install-ubuntu)

Comment: It's probable that your computer has secure boot, which means it will boot to Windows with UEFI by default. I think you need to reinstall, but with UEFI. If you're on Windows 8 or later, disable `Fast Startup`. Read here on how to create an EFI-only Ubuntu install media: http://askubuntu.com/questions/395879/how-to-create-uefi-only-bootable-usb-live-media/. You should also see if you can boot Ubuntu by using the BIOS boot menu. `boot-repair` may also be a good option. https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Repair

Comment: It's possible GRUB hasn't been installed or is installed on the wrong drive.

Comment: http://www.everydaylinuxuser.com/2014/05/install-ubuntu-1404-alongside-windows.html#7

Comment: Secure boot was off, didn't work. GRUB is installed as I can access it from the menu with the 4 options.

Answer (score 0):

First of all it looks like you downloaded an OEM version of Ubuntu.

I suggest installing a normal version from www.ubuntu.com.

Also after you installed Ubuntu you need to boot from your HDD, not from the installation media. You need to set it up in bios or just remove the installation media when you are prompted to reboot.

Comment: I download Ubuntu Desktop - Ubuntu 14.04.3 LTS

Comment: I did not try it yout, but normal Ubuntu iso did not have an OEM option. Maybe it has changed in 14.04.3.

Comment: I've removed the USB and tried to boot and it boots Windows, any idea why?